# What is the best way to authorize an AWS API call for a logged in user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, security, aws-lambda, oauth-2.0

I have a spring boot based web application which already authenticates the user. I would like to create some AWS APIs using AWS api gateway and a springboot rest app deployed on EC2. The user will log into the existing application and call the new AWS APIs from the browser ajax calls (like an SPA I guess but I have a server and can use client credentials/secrets if needed). What is the best way to handle security for the APIs. My first thought was to generate a JWT using a shared server side secret for hash and verify it with an AWS lambda. But this seems a bit non standard. Oauth2 might be better but might also be over kill. Not sure the performance would be good. Few requirements

- token passed to the API should be a user specific token and have an expiration (and hence a refresh token)
- The user is already logged into my web app and calling the api should not issue a login challenge.
- AWS API Gateway should be able to verify the token before passing it to the application
- Any token passed to the API should probably be generated on the logged in web application. Server knows the user is authenticated and should generate the user access token on behalf of the user. The AWS api should be able to figure out what privileges the user has based on the user principle or scopes in the token

I've thought about using Cognito AWS but I dont want to require the users to preexist in a user pool. Cognito seems geared more for the authentication rather than authorization and I would not be using the cognito login functionality. I dont know if its possible to use the oauth2/token endpoint alone with cognito.

Comment: You can use cognito Client Credential grant, the client can require JWT token knowing an app client id and secret,  with this solution no users must exist in the user pool. It's a common practice for machine-to-machine authentication 

https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/

Comment: This needs to generate a token for the end users. Each user needs to have access to just their own data. Think of an app like a banking app. User A shouldnt be able to use their access token to get account info for user B. I believe client credentials flow usually generates an access token on behalf of a system rather than a user.